# Swedish signs not working with SQL query

Tags: html, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am using Swedish characters in my SQL database, and they seem to be working fine there. But, when I want to display them in my HTML files, they don't seem to work and become question marks. Anyone knows how to fix something like this?

Comment: Please [edit] your questio to include the definition `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` of your table in MySQL. We're looking for the character set used to store the column of data that's malfunctioning.

Comment: When you hard code (not from database) Swedish signs in  your HTML, are they displayed normally?

Comment: Yes, when I hard code Swedish signs they work normally. I am using the latin1_swedish_ci character set.

Comment: What language do you use ? PHP? C#? ...

Comment: I code using PHP

Comment: Show us your PHP to  database connection code

Comment: For the connection to the database: <?php

$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Could not connect to database");
if(!$db)
  die("No Database");
if(!mysql_select_db("chemistry", $db))
  die ("No Database Selected");

For fetching stuff from the table: $info="SELECT * from table where name='$Name'";
$info2=mysql_query($info) or die("Wrong link. This page does not exist.");
$info3=mysql_fetch_array($info2);

Comment: There doesnt seem to be anything weird with the imported data besides the Swedish signs

Comment: Stop using `mysql_` functions. They have been deprecated for years now, and versions since PHP 7 don't support them anymore.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: Please take the contents of your comment at `Apr 8 at 11:42` and edit them into the question, using the formatting tools. Thanks! As it stands the question does not have enough detail to be regarded as on-topic. I appreciate it is already solved, but we still would like questions to be maintained here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the charset in the "connect" file to utf8 worked.

Comment: Please click the green tick mark adjacent to this answer, so it is marked as accepted. Thanks.